# Python Excercicse

Tags: python

I decided to make myself a little bit more useful, so I thought that learning computer languages would be a pretty good idea. I started with python, because I everyone I asked recommended it for a beginner.

I found an interactive website to do some exercises before going to the developing tool for practice. I know most of you will laugh, but I got stuck at exactly this point:

```
x = object()
y = object()

# change this code
x_list = [x]
y_list = [y]
big_list = []

print "x_list contains %d objects" % len(x_list)
print "y_list contains %d objects" % len(y_list)
print "big_list contains %d objects" % len(big_list)

# testing code
if x_list.count(x) == 10 and y_list.count(y) == 10:
    print "Almost there..."
if big_list.count(x) == 10 and big_list.count(y) == 10:
    print "Great!"
```

Well, I figured out the `big_list`. I have to write `[x_list * 10 + y_list * 10]`

The thing that I cannot figure out the last 30 minutes, is what values to I need to set in the `object` brackets (1st line of the command)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Don't really understand what you're asking. Why don't you share the website and we can check it out?

Comment: Tried to fix typo in title. It said the question with this title already exists.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're looking at: [Basic Operators - Learn Python](http://www.learnpython.org/Basic_Operators)

They are showing how operators + and * can apply to lists as well as other types. I'm too unhelpful to just give a solution, but here's a nudge in the right direction (I hope):

```
>>> 3 * 6
18
>>> "hi" * 6
'hihihihihihi'
>>> ["hi"] * 6
['hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi']
>>> my_list = ["hi"]
>>> my_list *= 6
>>> my_list
['hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi']
>>> my_list.count("hi") == 6
True
>>> [1,2,3] + [4,5,6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

When learning and exploring Python in general, I highly recommend experimentation like this in an interactive python shell.

Answer (score 0):

Well from your question, object() doesnt take any arguments with it. I mean in the brackets.

It is just used to create an empty object of object type.

Usually classes that we create in python will inherit this object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with `object`.

`object` is just an identifier that refers to a built-in type, in python all class inherit from object. Just for example purpose author has used it, you are just creating a instance of object so you don't need to pass anything to it.

To verify this, launch the python interpreter and do this

```
>>>x=object()
>>>print x
<object object at 0x01E214D8>
```

now if you print the doc string

```
>>>print x.__doc__
'The most base type'
```

Now back to your code

`x_list = [x]` here you are adding x (type object) to the list .

if you do `x_list = [x,1,'hello']` so now your list has an object, integer and string

Particular to this example You don't have to do anything to `x`, all the operations you should apply on lists (x_list,y_list and big_list). Python has very nice `dir` function, when passed with argument it returns list of valid attributes `dir(x_list)`